# "Unexpected_end, expecting keyword_end"

Tags: ruby

I have an issue in one of my functions in my code. I am new to Ruby, so I am unsure of where my syntax error is. My irb is giving me a syntax error related to my end keywords, but I believe the syntax is correct

```
def function1
  print "function 1 \n"
  print "Please type 4 lines \n"
  i = 0
  fptr = (File.new("myFile.txt", "w"))
  while i < 4
    line = gets
    fptr.write(line "\n")
    i++
  end    
  fptr.close()
end
```

This function should print two output lines, open a txt file, take in 4 lines of user input, and write them to the said file.

Comment: Sorry new to the Ask questions on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `i++` is not valid Ruby. Use `i += 1` instead.